# SSRS, subtotal on each line

Tags: reporting-services, subtotal

I just tried to make a grouped table in ssrs (let me show an exemple, more explicit than words...)

```
Date    | group1 | group2 | qty  | qty2 | sum
---------------------------------------------
20150202| ADSL   | france |  500 | 300  |1600
20150203| T1     | france | 1000 | 200  |1600
20150204| ADSL   | france |  100 |  50  |1600
```

as you can see, `sum(qty)=1600` ... i would like to have this 1600 at the end of each line group by "group 2" (in this case, "france")

I try to use "runingvalue", but this doesn't work "as expected" ....
When all my datas are regrouped (by date) sum is correct, but when i ungroup it, sum = qty, or qty + previous qty (depending on what i put in my runningvalue parameters)

```
=RunningValue(Fields!qte.Value,sum,Nothing) <= qty+previous qty

=RunningValue(Fields!qte.Value,sum,"group 2") <= qty
```

Can someone give me a way to look at, because i'm nearly sure that runningvalue is not the function I need...
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am bit confused as what you want ? Can you add expected output here ?

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally use RunningValue in reports I author. The key is making sure your scope parameter is correct. I've found that ALWAYS specifying a scope in that parameter is a good idea. If you want your Tablix un-grouped, use the following:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!qte.Value, sum, "DataSetNameGoesHere")
```

Grouped I believe you have correct.

Answer (score 0):

After more search, I found what I want there : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/5ee3c115-a02b-4295-91a4-e8df8b7f01c9/ssrs-problem-with-subtotal-and-calculating-percentage

(sorry if I confused you "Coder of Code" in my request...here is exactly what I was expecting)